# Application pool private memory limit is 0

Tags: iis

I'm new to IIS. I have several questions about recycling application pool:

1. Private memory limit and Vitual memory limit are all 0 by default. I read the official document of IIS 7.0 (We are using IIS 8.0 and Windows Server 2012 but I think they should be the same in this respect). So there is really no limit for the memory usage? It's just waiting 1740 minutes (by default) for the application to recycle? It won't recycle even if the total memory usage is very high until 1740 minutes later? I searched very hard for the answers but couldn't find any...
2. I read an article which said application pool should never be recycled. So what is the mechanism of memory management for IIS? When would the memory not being used be released? Is it similar to Java? I think no one said that full GC in Java is no good practice...

Thanks.